# Express the coefficients of $\exp(f(x))$ using the coefficients of $f(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Given a formal series

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k x^k$$ what is 
$$K_n:=\left[\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n e^{f(x)}\right]_{x=0}$$ in terms of the coefficients $\{f_k\}$?

I stumbled upon this problem when playing with some examples for normal form construction. I looked at the first terms by hand and obtained

$$K_0 =1 \\ K_1=f_1 \\ K_2=f_1^2+2f_2 \\ K_3=f_1^3+6f_1f_2+6f_3^3 \\ K_4=f_1^4+12f_1^2 f_2+24 f_1f_3+24f_4$$ but I can't see a pattern or get an idea to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \exp f(x) = f'(x)\exp f(x)
$$

Now use the Leibnitz formula:
$$
\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} \exp f(x)\left.\right|_{x=0}
=\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}f'(x)\exp f(x)\left.\right|_{x=0}\\
=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk
f^{(n-k+1)}(0)\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}\exp f(x)\left.\right|_{x=0}
$$

That is
$$
K_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk
f_{n-k+1}(n-k+1)! K_k
=\sum_{k=0}^n (n-k+1)\frac{n!}{k!} f_{n-k+1}K_k
$$

Comment: Thanks! Do you think there might be a chance to solve this recursion?

Comment: This recurrence relation is discussed in this paper: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00120324 (see also 
http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0080958 which is free).  Given the importance of this problem, people have worked on this.  mookid's seems to be the best answer to date.